# Is it possible to have multiple default values.yaml files embedded in a chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I know I can run `helm install -f` or `helm install --set` and I already have my helm deployments setup with a default yaml and environment specific yamls that are applied via `-f` on deploy.

But I have some cases where I want to easily apply a totally different bunch of settings and not have to use `--set` a bunch of times or require a local file be present.

So in the chart I would have a `remote-deployment.yaml` and a `local-deployment.yaml` and users can install the chart directly (without having to pull down some repo or have some local file) with a command like `helm install --default-values-file localy-deployment.yaml`

I could add a ton of conditionals to my chart and just use a single `--set` arg but having this specific set of settings in its own file would be cleaner and easier to maintain.

Is such a thing possible with helm?

Answer (score 0):

Helm `-f` flag supports both local and remote files much like the `kubectl` command.

Example:

```
helm install <my-release> chart/chart -f local-values.yaml
helm install <my-release> chart/chart -f https://website.com/remote-values.yaml
```